# Distributed integer factorization?

Tags: rsa, factoring

I'm looking around for publicly published work on factorization of large numbers using distributed systems of any kind. So far I've come across the PDF ["Mapreduce for integer factorization" by Javier Tordable](http://www.javiertordable.com/files/MapreduceForIntegerFactorization.pdf)" which looks like an interesting read.

Are there any papers in particular that I should be reading?

Comment: How large are the semi primes you want to factor? AFAIK the most expensive subprocess for 512 bit and 1024 moduli is a different one, and one of them is hard to distribute.

Comment: Depending on what specifically you're looking for, multiple papers might come handy. If you could describe your exact "use case", it would be easier to provide on-point information and papers/references...

Comment: @eQuiNoX__ did you take a look at [this paper](http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~edix/public_html_rennes/cours/brent.pdf)?

Comment: It may presumably be useful for your purposes to contact persons who are actively running projects of integer factorization with distributed computing. Google for that. (A link I found offhand is http://www.leyland.vispa.com/numth/factorization/main.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Last year the paper [Factoring as a Service](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/1000.pdf) was published, where Amazon EC2 is used to factorize a 512bit RSA modulus in just four hours for $75.
As far as I know, that is currently the fastest/cheapest approach actually used.

Answer (score 0):

The RSA-250 cryptographic challenge, solution by distributed computing [was computed](https://phys.org/news/2020-03-cryptographic.html) using [CADO-NFS](http://cado-nfs.gforge.inria.fr/), a number field sieve software package that can also be run in parallel.

A more accessible article can be found on [phys.org](https://lists.gforge.inria.fr/pipermail/cado-nfs-discuss/2020-February/001166.html) which does however contain a lot of advertisements.

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. This is a link only answer that we consider them as a comment and that you cannot comment yet. Could you update your answer with some details like [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1982/18298)