# How to attack RSA with 13 primes

Tags: encryption, rsa, cryptanalysis

Could give me method to attack RSA when N decomposes into multiple primes
And this is the topic
N = 18086135173395641986123054725350673124644081001065528104355398467069161310728333370888782472390469310073117314933010148415971838393130403883412870626619053053672200815153337045022984003065791405742151350233540671714100052962945261324862393058079670757430356345222006961306738393548705354069502196752913415352527

e = 9074407119435549226216306717104313210750146895081726439798095976354600576814818348656600684713830051655944443364224597709641982342039946659987121376590618828822446965847273448794324003758131816407702456966504389655568712152599077538994030379567217702587542326383955580601916478060973206347266442527564009737910

You can decode it?

Comment: $N$ decomposes to $42$ primes, not $13$.

Answer (score 4):

> Could give me method to attack RSA when N decomposes into multiple primes

First, factor `N`, e.g. using [trial division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division) or [Pollard's rho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm). Next, compute the decryption exponent, or use the method described in [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/31112/12164) to the question *“RSA enc/decryption with multiple prime modulus using CRT”*.

> You can decode it?

Yes.

---

**Nota bene:** If you expect a more in-deep answer, you should [edit your question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/58421/edit) and describe what research you have done, what you have tried, and where exactly you got stuck. For further details, read [How do I ask a good question?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) (I‘m posting this as a “community wiki” answer so it can be modified by anyone to adapt things in case you edit your question.)