# Factoring two RSA modulus with known $|p_1 - p_2| < \ell $

Tags: rsa

I have two 1024bit RSA modulus $N_1 = p_1q_1$ and $N_2 = p_2q_2$ such that $0 <|p_1 - p_2| < \ell$, and $\ell$ is at most 64bit integer. Can I factorise $N_1$ and $N_2$?
What's the answer when $p_1$ and $p_2$ are same $\alpha$-bit primes?

Comment: if $p_1=p_2$ you can simply compute the greatest-common-divisor of $N_1$ and $N_2$ to factor them.

Comment: @CodesInChaos   Yes of course it's obvious. But We can imagine some approximation as like those of Coppersmith and developped later by D. Boneh and al.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Have any solution for this $p_1 - p_2 = 2$?

Comment: How about [this](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/19733/small-prime-difference-in-rsa)?

Comment: @mikeazo: in the present question $0<|p_1-p_2|<\ell$, in the other question that you linked (transposing the notation to match that in the present question), we have $|p_1-q_1|<\ell$. $\;$ I have not understood the [proposed attack](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/22940/555), and fail to see one. $\;$ I second Lisbeth's [approach](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/22938/555#comment53288_22938) to first try to solve the problem with $p_1-p_2=2$.

Comment: @fgrieu that is what I get for not reading the whole question. I mean it is so long...

Answer (score 1):

**Outline of a elementary attack:**

if $\mid p_i-q_i \leq 2^s$, we can write for each $p_i=a.2^s+\tau_i$, with  $\tau_i \leq 2^s$, and we can imagine that if we determine the integer a, we can factor $N_i$ by a brute force attack.
We know that $p_i$ have exactly the same bit size and if $N_i$ have exactly the same bit size (n=1024, 2048, ... s=64), the sizes of $q_i$ could differ by at most one.

Let $r=\frac{a.2^s+\tau_1}{a.2^s+\tau_2} \approx 1 + \frac{1}{a} \pm \epsilon$.
And $\rho=\frac{N_1}{N_2} \approx (1 + \frac{1}{a} \pm f(\epsilon))\times \frac{q_1}{q_2}$ is a rational number which can be determined with a infinite precision.

Then by the examination of the bit of this ratio we can get information on the unknow number a, and hope to success in the factorisation Pb, in complexity less than the general know attacks.

Probably with the help of LLL algo we can enhance the attack.

Comment: It seems that you mean $|p_i - p_j| \le 2^s$, in this situation for $|p_1 - p_2| = 2^1$, $p_1 = a.2^s + \tau_1$ and $p_2 = a.2^s + \tau_2$ there is no solution for $a$. Same state for $|p_1 - p_2| = 2^2$. Why you say that there is such presentation for all $p_i$? I suppose that all $\tau_i$ are non-negative.

Comment: @Lisbeth: This is your configuration. $p_1$ and $p_2$ have in common the n/2-s upper bits. For 1024, roughtly 512-64=448  the upper 448 bits of $p_1$ and $p_2$ are identical.

Comment: @Lisbeth: I didn' see your last post. for s=1, you are in the case of twin primes. Try to do the same approximation to study if the problem has a solution. They have 510 bit in common.

Comment: @Lisbeth: You can reverse the problem for testing purpose. Firstly generate two twin primes of 512 bits, and use them to build $N_1$ and $N_2$. Then you can test the validity of the above attack. Bye!

Comment: Hey
for twin primes:
$p = 13407807929942597099574024998205846127479365820592393377723561443721764030073546976801874298166903427690031858186486050853753882811946569946433649006149569$
there is not $a$ such that $p = 2a + \tau_1$ and $p + 2 = 2a + \tau_2$, is there?

Comment: No you should adapt with this. In this case $s2$. Otherwise you can observe that your number are even. I will be unavailable for 3 days. Bye.

Comment: I fail to see how the examination of the bits of the ratio$N_1\over N_2$ reveals information on $a$ (as stated in the but-last paragraph of the [current answer](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/22940/2)). As a minor aside, $|p_1-p_2|\le2^s$ is not quite a sufficient condition to insure that $\lfloor p_1/2^s\rfloor=\lfloor p_2/2^s\rfloor$, thus existence of $a$. That part is easily fixable: with $s=\lceil\log_2\ell\rceil+4$, it is quite likely $a$ exists.