# RSA with exponent being a factor of modulus

Tags: rsa, public-key, modular-arithmetic, number-theory

This weekend I participated in a CTF, but came across a task that I wasn't able to solve. I can't find any write-ups so I hope you can help me.

Given:
$$
n = pq\\
c_1\cong m_1^{\hspace{.3em}p} \mod n\\
c_2\cong m_2^{\hspace{.3em}q} \mod n
$$
Knowing the values of $c_1,c_2,n$ and that $p$ is 1024 bit and $q$ is 1000 bit, with $p,q$ being prime. Is there an efficient way to recover $m_1,m_2$?

I know that if I'm able to recover $p,q$ it's trivial due to Fermat's theorem, but then again that problem is what makes RSAP hard.

The only other information given was that both $m_1,m_2$ were 25 bytes (200 bits). There was no service that could act as an oracle.

Comment: Please note that as a CTF we should treat this as an assignment and only provide hints, preferably in the comments.

Comment: The CTF has ended, so I wouldn't consider it an assignment. But hints are more than welcome as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key idea here is that $m_1$ (or $m_2$) is very small relatively to the modulus. This lets us apply the [usual Coppersmith techniques](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/89856/592).

We know that $c_1 = m_1^p \bmod n$, which entails $c_1 \equiv m_1 \bmod p$. From this we know that $c_1 - m_1 = t\cdot p$, for some $t$. In other words, $\gcd(c_1 - x, n) = p \ge n^{1/2}$ for some $x = m_1 \le n^{1/4}$. Here our expected $x = m_1$ is much smaller than $n^{1/4}$, in fact, which makes things easier to compute.

This is easily reproducible in Sage:

```
sage: p = random_prime(2^1024, lbound=2^1023+2^1022)                                                                                                          
sage: q = random_prime(2^1000, lbound=2^999+2^998)                                                                                                            
sage: n = p*q                                                                                                                                                 
sage:                                                                                                                                                         
sage: m1 = randint(0, 2^200)                                                                                                                                  
sage: m2 = randint(0, 2^200)                                                                                                                                  
sage: c1 = power_mod(m1, p, n)                                                                                                                                
sage: c2 = power_mod(m2, q, n)                                                                                                                                
sage:                                                                                                                                                         
sage: P.<x> = Zmod(n)[]                                                                                                                                       
sage: f = (c1 - x).monic()                                                                                                                                    
sage: f.small_roots(beta=0.5)                                                                                                                                 
[1106883791702122199703869965196585780508362129433642126297878]
sage: m1                                                                                                                                                      
1106883791702122199703869965196585780508362129433642126297878
```

Recovering $m_2$ can be done the same way, or by recovering the factors once $m_1$ is recovered—$p = \gcd(c_1 - m_1, n)$—and decrypting $m_2$ normally.

Comment: I do not see from the problem statement why $m_1$, $m_2$ are expected to be small?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen In a comment on another answer, OP writes: *"The only other information given is that both m_1,m_2 are 25 bytes, and of course that p,q are prime. There was no service that could act as an oracle."* Since this wasn't in a question, I'm guessing the answerer either saw that comment or had encountered this sort of CTF exercise elsewhere.

Comment: Correct, I saw the comment. Arguably this is also the sort of assumption you are usually expected to guess/try on CTFs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that, as stated, that problem is solvable; in the CTF contest, there may have been some additional information, or the exact values given for $n, c_1, c_2$ may have included some weakness.

I believe that the Clifford Cox [1] scheme (where the ciphertext is $m^n \bmod n$ is believed to be secure for $n$ of secret factorization); if you can solve the above problem for generate $n, c_1, c_2$, here is how to break that scheme:

- Given $c, n$, invoke the Oracle with $c_1 = c$, and $c_2$ arbitrary; that gives you a value $m_1$
- Then, invoke the Oracle again with $c_2 = m_1$ and $c_1$ arbitrary; the value $m_2$ that returns will be the decryption of the Cox encryption, that is, the value $m$ with $m^n \equiv c$.

[1] or Cocks; I've seen both spellings...

Comment: The only other information given is that both $m_1,m_2$ are 25 bytes, and of cause that $p,q$ are prime.
There was no service that could act as an oracle.