# Non probabilistic algorithm : Given secret key $d$ we can factorize $n$ assuming $e$ is small

Tags: rsa, factoring, number-theory

I read in an introduction to a paper that if $e$ is small enough and we were given secret key $d$ in RSA, then there is an efficient deterministic algorithm to factorize $n$. I've searched about that and I've found the probabilistic one: [Algorithm to factorize $N$ given $N$, $e$, $d$](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/62482/algorithm-to-factorize-n-given-n-e-d)

I guess, the fact that $e$ is small must play some role here. But I was able to come up with something. Do you know anything?

Comment: See [this paper](https://iacr.org/archive/crypto2004/31520213/det.pdf) by Alexander May.

Comment: Or Jean-Sebastien Coron and Alexander May's [Deterministic Polynomial Time Equivalence of Computing the RSA Secret Key and Factoring](https://eprint.iacr.org/2004/208), in [JoC 2007](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00145-006-0433-6), which is later, and may have some refinements.

Answer (score 1):

The [May-Coron](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00145-006-0433-6) result for balanced RSA moduli can be seen as essentially an application of the [Coppersmith theorem](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/89856) to the polynomial
$$
f(x) = n - x \bmod (de-1)\,,
$$
where we are looking for the root $p+q-1 \approx n^{1/2}$ modulo $\varphi(n) \approx n$—a divisor of $de-1$.

The Coppersmith theorem says that we can find a root of $f(x)$ smaller than $(de-1)^{\beta^2}$ modulo an unknown divisor $\varphi(n)$ of $de-1$ of size $(de-1)^{\beta}$. Translating this to our setting, suppose $de-1 = n^{k}$. Then $n \approx (de-1)^{1/k}$. Setting $\beta=1/k$ and taking logarithms, we have that $k\cdot (1/k)^2 \ge 1/2$ implies $k \le 2$, which means that the factorization can be found in polynomial time as long as $de-1 \le n^2$. As such, it is not strictly $e$ that needs to be sufficiently small, but the product $ed$.

Comment: maybe you meant to say $f(x) = x^2 - n$ ? because that's when $ n^{1/2}$ is a root

Comment: Why we assume $p+q-1 \approx n^{1/2} \mod \phi(n)$? We have $\phi(n) = (p-1)(q-1)$ $p+q-1= (p-1) + (q-1) + 1 \mod \phi(n) = 1$

Comment: $n - (p + q - 1) \equiv 0 \pmod{\varphi(n)}$. When I use $\approx$ above, it means "roughly of the same size".