# Find a constant $C$ in $O(Cn^2)$?

Tags: rsa, complexity

I am writing a paper on RSA, and I am calculating some encryption running times.

I have been told that the encryption running time is $O(n^2)$ where $n$ is the modulus. I have also been told that there is a constant $C$ such that $O(Cn^2)$ where $C$ relates to the machine used.

Does anyone have any idea where to find this $C$ for a certain computer?

Comment: Ok, but will the little-o notation give me the running time for RSA encryption? I am trying to find an upper bound for the public key exponent, so I decided on a max. time - the other factor is how quickly my computer can handle the computations (right?).

Comment: You seem to confuse public exponent ($e$) and public modulus ($N$, with $n$ the number of bits in $N$); and have trouble putting Big-O notation to practical use. This [answer](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/30359/555) might help for both. The software running on your computer matters more than your computer does.

Comment: I am not confusing them. But if I set an upper bound for N, I am effectively setting an upper bound for e because e cannot be greater that the totient of N. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Mathematica Just benchmark different key sizes.

Comment: By definition $O(n^2) = O(Cn^2)$ for any constant $C$ so the notation is at least not quite right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't seem to understand what complexity means. $O(Cn^2) = O(n^2)$, so *“finding $C$”* is not a valid question – any positive $C$ will do.

I recommend looking up some [basic complexity theory introduction](https://dionyziz.com/complexity/). There are many [introductory books](http://beust.com/algorithms.pdf) on the [subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms) which can help you understand what this means.