# IN RSA encryption why do the values of p and q need to be far apart?

Tags: rsa

I was doing research into RSA and i read that the prime numbers need to be far apart in order to strengthen the key. Why is that?

Comment: Fermat factoring.... Let me find you a dupe.

Comment: 1. [RSA and prime difference](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/5262/18298) 2. [Should RSA primes p and q differ in length by "a few digits"?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/35087/18298)