# Parameters and key dimension for DH and RSA

Tags: rsa, public-key, diffie-hellman, key-exchange

I studied RSA and Diffie-Hellman key exchange from a quite old book (Discrete Mathematics by Berardi, Beutelspacher) and so I wonder if the recommended dimensions for the prime *p* and the secret numbers *a* and *b* of the DH key exchange and for the RSA's public key are still valid or not. The dimensions are 1024 for the prime in RSA and the same for the group of DH.

I tried to find an answer online but I found several different opinions.
Can anyone share his knowledge and/or experience about it? I would appreciate also references to data from valid online resources.

Comment: What book? What dimensions?

Comment: By dimensions, I assume he means size.

Comment: "Discrete Mathematics" - Berardi, Beutelspacher. 1024 bit for n=pq in RSA, the same for p in DH key exchange.

Comment: @M-elman: actually, that advice is rather outdated...

Comment: @poncho It's the reason why I asked. I want to know which sizes are considered secure nowadays.

Comment: See [http://keylength.com](http://keylength.com) and / or it's links. DH = discrete logarithm.

Comment: This is a useful website, thank you. Is the "key" in the Discrete Logarithm section the recommended  lenght of a and b in DH key exchange?

Comment: I think [_this_](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1978/23623) is our canonical ressource on this subject (for RSA at least).

Comment: @M-elman Yes, that's it. Note that - although there are certainly differences between the algorithms - that the group size in DH is generally identical to the size of the RSA modulus/private key when strength is considered.