# RSA finding p and q integer with condition

Tags: rsa, prime-numbers, factoring

I'm given $N=p\,q$ and told that $44\,p\approx 17\,q$ (with the value given for $N$ some 49-digit integer `8124642558124642555899928124642555899924479992447`).

In RSA $p$ and $q$ must be prime.

So how can I solve this equation?

I'm using Maple, I began with s := evalf(solve(eqns, [p, q])) with eqns := {N = p*q, 44*p = 17*q}.

The result is not a prime number. How can I put another condition to force $p$ and $q$ to be prime? Or am I missing something?

<sub>Note of the editor: superlative HUGE removed for $N$, since it is way too small for RSA being secure.</sub>

Comment: Well come to [Cryptograhy](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help). Is this a homework question or from a CTF? If so, please write it down with the source. What have you tried?  The question will be better; Let $n =p q$,  $p$ and $q$ are two disntinct primes, with the following relation $i q \approx j q$ where $i$ and $j$ are small primes.

Comment: and the second condition is $i p \approx j q$? The question is not clear.

Comment: Hi, sorry let me clarify the question. I have an exemple N= 812464255589992447, and 44*p ≈ 17q. how can i find p and q (RSA) ? p and q must be integer and primes at the same times. Thanks for your help

Comment: ip≈jq like 44*p ≈ 17q

Comment: Note: the problem statement does NOT says that $44\,p = 17\,q$. Arithmetic is an exact science! Hint: What would happen if you tried to factor $44\cdot17\,N$ by [Fermat's factoring method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_method)?

Comment: @fgrieu the $N$ has 4 factors. if you multiply both sides by $q$ and $17$ we will get $4 \cdot 11 \cdot 17 \cdot N = 17^2 q^2$ but the smallest prime factors of $n$ are $527$ and $1747$. So equality is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

The question's attempt at resolution is headed in the wrong direction for two related reasons

- It informs the math tool that `44*p = 17*q` when the problem statement has $44\,p\approx 17\,q$. If we had $44\,p=17\,q$, then $p$ and $q$ could not be primes, as stated in the problem.
- It is not informing the math tool that $p$ and $q$ are integers. I can't help about how to do that for Mapple, and it is off-topic anyway.

---

$N$ is way too small to be useful as an RSA modulus, and could be easily factored without the hint that $44\,p\approx 17\,q$. Anything below 100 decimal digits has long been factorable by a single PC in minutes (see [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1982/555)); the lowest considered reasonable by Y2K was 1024 bits ≈ 309 digits; current is double that, moving to triple or away from RSA in the long run.

---

This is an application of [Fermat's factoring method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_method). This method is very efficient to factor integers of the form $C=A\,B$ with $A\approx B$. The hint $44\,p\approx17\,q$ tells that $C=44\cdot17\,N$ must be of this form, with $\{A,B\}=\{44\,p,17\,q\}$. Once we have factored $44\cdot17\,N$ using Fermat's factoring method, we can easily get at $p$ and $q$.

Don't fall into the trap of thinking that we must specifically guard against Fermat's factoring method and extensions when choosing an RSA key. The likelihood that the product of random primes $p$ and $q$ of practical size can be factored in this way is infinitesimal.

---

Update: there must be some typo in the value given for $N$, since (as commented by kelalaka) the integer given has 4 prime factors.