# Choosing a suitable prime for accumulators

Tags: hash, accumulators

I am trying to work out accumulators and generate $S = \{ e_1,e_2 \ldots, e_n \} $ from [this](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Jasminka_Hasic_Telalovic/publication/2525441_Lecture_Notes_in_Computer_Science/links/565d134308ae4988a7bb92c6.pdf) (Section 3.4 - Choosing a Suitable Prime).

For each element of $e_i$ compute its representation $x_i$.(This I want to calculate).

**To compute representation($x_i$) use following**
( According to the paper $x_i$ should be calculated like this and this part I need help with. Please help me understand this)

We are interested in obtaining a prime solution of the linear system, that represents a Universal-2 hash function.

**Lemma:**
*Let H be a universal-2 family from $\{0,1\}^{3k}$ to $\{0,1\}^k$. Then, for all but a $2^{-k}$ fraction of the functions $h \in H$. For every $e \in \{0,1\}^k$ a fraction of at least $1/ck$ of the elements in $f^{-1}(e)$ are primes, for some small constant c.*

*We accept a prime inverse only if it is greater than $\sqrt{2^{3k}}$. Since domain of H is $\{0,1\}^{3k}$. So, by the results of prime number theory, the density of big prime numbers that are less than $2^k$ is about $1/2k$ for all but a $2^{\Omega(k)}$* fraction of functions in family H.*

**Please help me, how can I calculate $x_i$ as a representation of $e_i$?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll use as reference Michael T. Goodrich, Roberto Tamassia, Jasminka Hasic's [*An Efficient Dynamic and Distributed RSA Accumulator*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.1307.pdf#page=8) from [arXiv (2009)](https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.1307), not the version originally [in proceedings of ISC 2002](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-45811-5_29) or linked in the question.

Disclaimer: I discover this paper while writing this answer, thus **the following is highly tentative. Further, there are important things that I fail to make sense of, which means my understanding or the paper is wrong. Therefore, do not use the following for anything more serious than an exploration.**

---

#### Preliminary: choice of RSA modulus $N=P\,Q$, and base $a$.

When it is wished to store $e_i$ of up to $k$ bits, the scheme as described starts by generating “strong primes¹” $P$ and $Q$ of at least $3k/2$ bits each. I believe they additionally need to be at least as large as required for security of RSA (that's not stated). The article's Experimental Results states "the parameter $N$ of the RSA accumulator is a 200-bit integer", but if I understand the rest suggests $k=165$, which would make $N$ 495-bit. Even this would have been too low when the article came out, see [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1982/555). Such disregard for a safe choice of $N$ in both the theoretical and practical parts of the article is crying to be fixed. I'll have a try at that.

The article's reference for “strong primes¹” is the [Handbook of Applied Cryptography definition 4.52](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap4.pdf#page=18):

> A prime number $p$ is said to be a strong prime if integers $r$, $s$, and $t$ exist such that the following three conditions are satisfied:
>  (i)    $p−1$ has a large² prime factor, denoted $r$;
>  (ii)   $p+1$ has a large² prime factor, denoted $s$; and
>  (iii)  $r−1$ has a large² prime factor, denoted $t$.

In the context of RSA accumulators and problems that rely on the Strong RSA assumption (including the question's scheme), I would require at least (i) to hold for $P$ and $Q$; and for good measure I'd use [safe primes](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-48285-7_24.pdf) of the same bit size, as required in the article's reference [6], Josh Benaloh and Michael de Mare's [*One-way accumulators: A decentralized alternative to digital signatures*](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-48285-7_24.pdf), in [proceedings of Eurocrypt 1993](https://doi.org10.1007/3-540-48285-7_24) (with [extended abstract](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/1993/01/owa.pdf)).

For a modern implementation I would consider $k=680$, and $P$ and $Q$ random 1024-bit safe primes in the interval $[2^{1023.5},2^{1024})\,$, which are easy to generate.

Also, it's required “a suitably-large base $a$ that is relatively prime to $N=P \,Q$”. For lack of other guidance, I'd consider $a=\lfloor\pi\,2^{2045}\rfloor$.

---

#### Primes representative of the $e_i$ to be accumulated.

The paper defines a function
$$\begin{align}h:\{0,1\}^{3k}&\mapsto\{0,1\}^k\\
x\quad&\to h(x)\underset{\text{def}}=U\times x\end{align}$$
where $U$ is a binary matrix of $k$ lines and $3\,k$ columns. And it defines the prime representative of $e_i$ to be accumulated as a prime $p_i$ in $[2^{3k/2},2^{3k})$ such that $h(p_i)=e_i$ (assimilating integers to bitstrings per e.g. big-endian convention).

In order to find $p_i$ from $e_i$, we can simplify the system of $k$ binary equations with $3k$ binary unknowns $U\times x=e_i$, enumerate solutions at least $2^{3k/2}$, and stop at the first prime $x$ found. I located no requirement on the enumeration order, but I guess that it must be deterministic, and pseudo-random would not harm.

The rest seems standard use of an RSA accumulator.

---

¹ Note: In normal RSA, it's dubious that strong primes are really needed nowadays. Condition (i) [resp. (ii)] aims at blocking [Pollard's $p-1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_p_%E2%88%92_1_algorithm) [resp. [William's $p+1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Williams%27s_p_%2B_1_algorithm)] factoring, but that becomes hopeless as $p$ increases (as needed to resist [GNFS](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/pubs/RS01.version-1999-11-22.pdf)), and could only really help in multi-target attacks at low parametrization. Condition (iii) aims at blocking a cycling attack but seems pointless, see Ronald L. Rivest and Robert D. Silverman's [Are ‘Strong’ Primes Needed for RSA?](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/pubs/RS01.version-1999-11-22.pdf). None of these conditions are required by the conservative [FIPS 186-4 appendix B3](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=60) for primes 1024-bit or larger intended for RSA moduli used in signature.

² Nothing in either the paper or the HAC hints at how large in the context of RSA accumulators. The guidance in FIPS 186-4 is not intended for this context; using it for (i) would be adventurous.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a python library which does all this hard work?

Comment: @Tabz: not one I know. I'll ping you should that change, you got me hooked on RSA accumulators.

Comment: Your help is appreciated. will wait for your reply