# Does the signature length of RS256 depend on the size of the RSA key used for signing?

Tags: rsa, sha-256, jwt

The following NodeJS code, when run (v16.8.0), logs `512` to stdout.

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
const { privateKey } = crypto.generateKeyPairSync("rsa", {
    modulusLength: 4096,
});
const sign = crypto.createSign("RSA-SHA256").update("somestringtosign");
const signature = sign.sign(privateKey);
console.log(signature.length); // logs 512
```

If I change the modulus length to `2048`, then `256` is logged to standard out.

I guess this makes sense, as the [RSA spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3447#section-8.2.1) says: `signature, an octet string of length k, where k is the length in octets of the RSA modulus n`. So a 256 bit hash (SHA256), when signed with an RSA key with a 4096 bits modulus, has a 4096 bits (512 bytes) output.

Can the signature length in RS256 indeed be longer than 256, depending on the size of the RSA key used? Is it "weird" to use a modulus that is longer than the hash function used? I see various identity providers that sign JWTs indeed all use 2048 bits modulus, but that might be coincidental.

(I noticed the [IETF spec for RS256](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7518#section-3.3) says: `A key of size 2048 bits or larger MUST be used with these algorithms.` so apparently a modulus of 4096 would be allowed by the spec`)

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the comments and answers I now understand I asked the "wrong" question. I was (erroneously) expecting the length of the JWT's signature to equal the length of the hash digest produced by the hash algorithm (SHA256). I was therein confusing bits and bytes, because e.g SHA256 produces a digest of 256 bits (not bytes). The signature length I witnessed in my case was 256 bytes (not bits), which I now understand should equal the length of the public key's modulus (which indeed is the case as I was able to verify later).

Comment: Well, we have tons of questions about this. RSA signature needs padding to be secure that's RSA-PSS (search for RSA Probabilistic Signature Scheme). And also there is RSA-FDH (RSA-Full Domain Hash) signature and that is secure, too. In this case you need at least RSA-2048 and a hash function that can be output ~2047 bits like Shake128 of SHA3.

Comment: SHA-256 is a 256-BIT hash = 32 bytes not 256 bytes. Most cryptographic data is described in bits not bytes, although PKCS1 (nd JOSE) only supports _multiples_ of a byte (formally octet) of 8 bits. To be _secure_ RSA modulus must be much bigger than is needed for the hash -- SHA-256 gives 128-bit strength but RSA-3072 is needed to match it (and some people do 4096 because it looks nicer). See https://www.keylength.com and many many dozen existing questions.

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085! I edited and changed bytes to bit in the hash reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can the signature length in RS256 indeed be longer than 256, depending on the size of the RSA key used?

Yes. In RSA (including RS256, which is [RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#page=31) with SHA-256 as hash), the signature size depend on the size of the RSA key (actually, it's public modulus) used for signing. Specifically, the signature size (in bytes, before re-encoding as text) is the key size (in bit), divided by 8 and rounded up to the next integer. $\lceil 2048/8\rceil=256$ bytes. $\lceil 4096/8\rceil=512$ bytes.

> Is it "weird" to use a modulus that is longer than the hash function used?

No. That's even required. From a formatting standpoint, the minimum signature size for RS256 (RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 with SHA-256) would be $2+8+1+19+32=62$ bytes, that is a 489-bit public modulus. That would be way too small to be secure, though. 2048-bit is considered the baseline for new applications. It's expected to provide 112-bit to 128-bit security against classical computers, comparable to a 224-bit or 256-bit hash's collision resistance. See [this](https://keylength.com/) for recommendations on key size, and [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1982/555) for the status of factorization attacks.

I know no standard upper limit, and I see no reason for an implementation not to support at least 2048-byte (16384-bit) signatures.