# Historical key sizes for RSA and discrete log

Tags: encryption, rsa, discrete-logarithm, key-size, factoring

What is the historical pattern for key size increases for rsa vs discrete log?

What are the current and future projected sizes for these?

Comment: [RSA's path is easy](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1978/18298),  Dlog, on the other hand, is a bit complex since we have multiplicative and additive (elliptic) and they have many paths to go. Your question is lack of research and too broad to answer.